# Creating a data warehouse with SQL Server 2008 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, etl, data-warehouse, denormalization, star-schema

I need to build a Data Warehouse for an existing SQL Server database. I already have the design of the star schema dimension and fact tables. My question is:

Is there a tool in SQL Server 2008 Enterprise to help me with translating my data from the transactional database into the new data warehouse database? I am looking for a tool that helps me cleanup my data and populate the warehouse tables. I have done this before in an academic environment using Oracle databases. In this case I had to do everything "manually" with SQL.

Comment: When I Google this, SSIS comes up. There are even other questions in this site that mention SSIS related to this subject. I can create SSIS packages that I can run daily (for example) to do the rollup, but I haven't found how to use this effectively to do the initial ETL, which includes playing with the data to try different alternatives. Maybe I am just missing the elephant in the room.

Comment: There is no automagical solution. If there were, I would be skeptical because there would be many automatic transformations done by said solution that may ignore important business rules. SSIS is probably the best choice for your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check IMPORT and EXPORT functionality of MS - SQL SERVER, watch this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDfhTPU7P-M

Answer (score 1):

you should learn SSIS (not that hard) but first step is to load data. Quick and dirty way to do this is Import/Export Wizard - once you go through its steps, you can even save it as SSIS package and then tweak it as needed.

Some developers use SSIS heavily specifically data flows to clean-up and conform data. Some developers use SSIS only to bring data to a staging area (tables) and then would use SQL Stored procedures to transform/manipulate data on SQL Server.